# Non transactional request tries to get a lock with Derby

Tags: spring, hibernate, derby

I am currently working with spring, hibernate and derby. Two processes are accessing the same database at the same time, one is transactional and making changes and the other is non-transactional and reading data. But the second one (the non-transactional one) is prevented from execution and the stack trace is :

```
12:02:29.743 [http-8080-1] DEBUG o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not execute query [select count(clienttemp0_.id) as col_0_0_ from CLIENT_TEMPLATE_SET clienttemp0_]
java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: A lock could not be obtained within the time requested
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.closeOnTransactionError(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.movePosition(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedResultSet.next(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.10.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.next(DelegatingResultSet.java:207) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
```

I would like to know why a non-transactional request is trying to get a lock. I have checked that it was really non-transactional by using @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER). With Postgres, both processes work fine. The transactional request has following parameters: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED, ISOLATION_DEFAULT. autoCommit is set to false.
I checked also that the requests in the transactional process all are included in the same transaction (according to the logs : `DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction`) whereas nothing indicates that it is the case for the non transactional process.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to say that it was about embedded derby, and according to the documentation, it does not allow several operations at the same time. see http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/devguide/
"Deployment options and threading and connection modes" section. It seems to answer my question. I will then see if I can change requirements.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at spring documentation for [propagation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html)

you set the non-transactional process to `propagation=Propagation.NEVER` which executes non-transactionally and doesn't support an existing and already running transaction (which ,in your case, is the second process ).
you should switch to `propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS` which will support a current transaction and execute non-transactionally if none exists.

Comment: At first I didn't put any @Transactional on my method and had the bug. I only tried Propagation.NEVER to validate that no transaction was used to execute the method. It is removed now. I want this request to be outside a transaction, so Propagation.SUPPORTS does not suit me but I have made the try and the result is the same. I still have the exception.
I would have expected that the result of the non-transactional request would be a dirty read but the fact that it tries to get a lock puzzles me

Comment: can you specify why do you want the process to execute outside a transaction ?